# How do I view my purchased movies and TV shows on my Mac?

Tags: icloud, streaming

I have a MBP (2009 unibody) with Mountain Lion.  I have iTunes Match, iCloud, blah blah blah.

Now when I open iTunes, I'm able able stream down my music but I can't stream movies or TV shows like I can on my AppleTV.

When I go to movies or TV all I get is a screen telling me how I can visit the store.

How can I stream my purchased movies and TV shows?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can stream small files like music but you can't 'stream' movies (huge files) from iCloud but any movie you have purchased via iTunes will be available through iCloud and 'pushed' to the device you are on. So for instance; you purchase a movie via your pc or mac through your iTunes account and then you pick up your iPad and go to iTunes Store, go to 'more' then purchased, click on your purchased movie from the list and you'll see your movie with a cloud icon. Click this and the film will be pushed to your device to view. But again it won't be actively streaming, rather it will be downloaded to your device! Hope this helps?